# Azure RBAC role assignments list filter on datetime range

Tags: azure-rest-api

I wanted to know if it is possible to list the azure rbac role assignments using Rest Api past 24 hours window. Meaning, I have [Rest Api][1] which results me all current role assignments. But I would like to see if we have an handy rest api which emits all role assignments done past 24 hours. I know I can tap on to Azure Activity logs but they don't record the entries if MS-PIMs did any role assignments from the backend.